# Button Handles after creating buttons in code

Tags: vb.net, events, button, handles

I have previously created buttons in my code, as shown:

```
Dim Itm As New Button
Itm.Name = "Itm" & i
Itm.Height = 62
Itm.Width = 159
Itm.Text = Temp(i, 0).ToUpper
Itm.Left = (F * 165)
Itm.Visible = True
Itm.BackColor = Colour
Itm.ForeColor = Color.Black
Me.pnlItemButton1.Controls.Add(Itm)
```

When I run the form, the buttons are created but I now need to create an Event Sub for when the new buttons are clicked. I have tried this:

```
    Private Sub Itm1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Itm1.click

End Sub
```

But get an error that 'handle clause requires with WithEvent'

So how can i do this
?

Also, the amount of buttons - Itm(i) is variable, so how can i create a handle that will account for Itm1 to Itm99?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic button click event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a dynamically added button it doesn't exist at runtime so you can't set an event handler like that, what you can do is the following:

```
Dim Itm As New Button
Itm.Name = "Itm" & i
Itm.Height = 62
Itm.Width = 159
Itm.Text = Temp(i, 0).ToUpper
Itm.Left = (F * 165)
Itm.Visible = True
Itm.BackColor = Colour
Itm.ForeColor = Color.Black
AddHandler Itm.Click, AddressOf Me.Itm1_Click
Me.pnlItemButton1.Controls.Add(Itm)
```

Then set a protected Event Handler:

```
Protected Sub Itm1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    
End Sub
```

Comment: But using that added line, is hard coding Itm1, when the Itm Name is in a loop with Itm & i, so will not always be Itm1?

Comment: Every added button will have the same EventHandler, there is no other way in Vb.net to dynamically add an EventHandler to a button besides this, also it isn't hardcoded, the only hardcoded part is your itm1_click

Answer (score 1):

For your first error, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674574/handles-clause-requires-a-withevents-variable-defined-in-the-containing-type-or). It may help you.

To create an event click for every button you create dynamically try this:

```
AddHandler Itm.Click, AddressOf Me.Itm1_Click
```

Then you don't need the `Handles Itm1.click` in your Sub:

```
Private Sub Itm1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object,ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   
       'Do stuff
End Sub
```